# Cursor jumps to corner of screen when I touch edges of touchpad/trackpad

Tags: touchpad, cursor, trackpad

When using Ubuntu 12.04, if I happen to touch one of the extreme edges of my touchpad, my cursor spontaneously jumps to the top left corner of the screen. I have tried disabling all touchpad features within system settings, but this behavior persists.

Is this a bug or a "feature" gone wrong? Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Similar behaviour here - except it jumps to the bottom left sporadically, almost always when I am about to use my left hand to left-click at the bottom left of the touchpad, and my right hand is elsewhere near (i.e. just touching on or above) the touchpad.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/792098/how-do-i-stop-the-cursor-jumping-from-desired-location-to-the-far-left-of-the-sc .

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some problem in your touchpad drivers. Try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it and am still experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Do you experience the same when booted from the Live USB or CD?

Comment: Interestingly, no.