# Cursor jumping to top-left of screen

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchscreen

I notice that sometimes when I wake my computer up from standby, or even booting it up,the cursor jumps to the left over and over. I go to move the mouse, in a second it will be back over to the top-left.

I can temporaily fix the issue by disabling touchscreen input by running xinput disable 9. I even created a keyboard shortcut. However, I want to be able to utilize the touch screen if possible.

I don't think this is a hardware issue because this never occurs mid-usage. Only upon wake, and sometimes upon boot. This issue did not occur when I had Windows 7 or Windows 10 on it. This started occuring a couple weeks after I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

- Computer: Lenovo Ideapad Flex 15
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
- OS Type: 64 Bit
- Disk: 484.0 GB

Comment: A related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/792098/how-do-i-stop-the-cursor-jumping-from-desired-location-to-the-far-left-of-the-sc

Answer (score 0):

I have never experienced this until today. Before the sleep cycle I had been experimenting with acceleration using `xset m _ _`

Sleeping the machine again with `sudo pm-suspend` and re-awakening it did not help.

What did solve it for me was unplugging and replugging the USB mouse!